# Do i need to uninstall my current version of the iPhone SDK (v3.2) in order to install the latest GM (v4.0)?

Tags: iphone

Do i need to uninstall my current version of the iPhone SDK (v3.2) in order to install the latest GM (v4.0)?  Or can I just download the latest SDK and run the installer?

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you can install the SDK 4 in a different location. That means you can have both version installed at the same time.

I haven't done that myself, though, so I'm not sure about the exact steps to follow. I assume there is a way to change the installation directory in the installer.

Comment: Yes there is, it will give you an option on what to install (parts of the SDK) and where, that's your chance, from the installer. Don't change the folder after you've made it.